# Objective-c macro with one or more args

Tags: objective-c, c, macros

I'm trying to learn macros in xcode, so i basically took a method such as **[self performSelectorInBackground:withObject:]** and tried to do a macro for it.

What i want is to write calls as follows:

```
bgex(@selector(somecall:))
// or
bgex(@selector(somecall:), obj, obj2...)
```

The following should translate to:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(somecall:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil]];
// and
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(somecall:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj, obj2, nil]];
```

So i figured i'd write something like this for a macro:

```
#define bgex(fn, ...) [self performSelectorInBackground:fn withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:__VA_ARGS__, nil]]
```

I haven't tried if it works yet, because i can't even compile it properly. Here's what i get:

```
bgex(@selector(somecall:), @"test") // compiles
bgex(@selector(somecall:)) // "expected expression" error
```

Does someone see what i'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `##__VA_ARGS__`? without the leading `##`, there'll be a trailing comma in the one-argument case (i. e. the macro will expand to `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:, nil]` which is a syntax error. Also, consider using the `@[]` sugar for creating immutable array literals; it's less error-prone and definitely more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My previous try was exactly with #__VA_ARGS__, but it failed with or without arguments in the call. It would say "pasting formed ':@', an invalid preprocessor token".

Comment: The special case for `##` preceding `__VA_ARGS__` is only to remove a comma before the `##`. That doesn't help here. However, the Croissant's suggestion to use the `@[]` syntax for creating an array literal does fix it, because there's no need for a trailing `, nil`, which means that an empty `__VA_ARGS__` doesn't lead to illegal syntax.

Comment: One of you guys should write this as an answer, because using @[] with __VA_ARGS__ did work. At least it compiled. Thank you both